# Automate Generation of RSS Feed

Tags: rss, feed

I'm wondering if anyone knows of a free website that will create an RSS feed for you on website that do not have RSS feed.

Example of this is http://www.feedyes.com/ . But this is a paid service...

Answer (score 1):

Yahoo Pipes will do this. Check out their [Fetch Page Module](http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/docs?doc=sources#FetchPage).

> There's more data on the web than just RSS and Atom feeds. This module fetches the source of a given web site as a string. This data can then be converted into an RSS feed or merged with other data in your Pipe using the Regex module.

Answer (score 0):

Does [FeedBurner](http://feedburner.google.com/) do what you want? (And if not, can you elaborate on your question?)

Comment: Actually it's not. I've been googling around and feed43 and feedfire are sites that can generate RSS feeds. For Feed43, I'm having troubling in understanding how  their system works while feedfire only updates the feeds every 24 hours.

Answer (score 0):

Google's "Google Reader" service will watch a website for changes for you if it doesn't have an RSS feed, simply add a subscription and provide the site / page URL. It works very well.